# How to disable "kinetic energy" of the UI object (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I have `Image` on View that I can drag. But when I release the object it is moving for some time. How I can disable this?

My `Xaml` code:

```
 <Image Grid.Column="0"
           x:Name="CollageImg1"
           Margin="370,469,1665,800"
           Source="{Binding CollageImg1}"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
           ManipulationDelta="CollageImgage1_Manipulation"
           Visibility="Visible">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

Method that uses for moving:

```
 private void Manipulation(ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e, Image image)
    { 
        CompositeTransform ct = (CompositeTransform)image.RenderTransform;
        ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;// X move
        ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;// Ymove
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [`TranslateInertia`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.manipulationmodes) from the `ManipulationMode` property of the Image.

E.g. set only `TranslateX` and `TranslateY`:

```
<Image ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY" ... />
```

Comment: Yes it help. Thanks!